# ResponseEntity without value return error

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I have a spring boot with thymeleaf application

An ajax call is made wit this code

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/subscriptionsavetestament",
    async: false,
    data: testamentJson,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',
    beforeSend: function(request) {
        request.setRequestHeader(header, token);
    },
    success: function(data){
       ....
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("error: " + textStatus);
    }
});
```

This controller is called

```
public ResponseEntity subscriptionsavetestament(@RequestBody TestamentWizard testamentDocument){
    ...
   return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

But I get alway an error on the javascript side error parsing...

If I modify my controller for

```
public ResponseEntity subscriptionsavetestament(@RequestBody TestamentWizard testamentDocument){
    ...
   return new ResponseEntity(true, HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

that work fine, but I don't understand why

how the ajax call must be done if the server return only the status,  nothing in the body?

Edit:

Removing dataType fix the issue

Comment: Because you are sending body in the second one but not in the first one. In your javascript code you are trying to parse body, in the first one which is not exists that causes problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can return empty body with 200 status code using following code

```java
@GetMapping("/empty")
public ResponseEntity<Void> empty() {
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

If you do not want to send 200 then a better way would be directly use `noContent` this will give HTTP 204

```java
return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
```